# React Native Disable Ligatures

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, react-native, fonts

Is there anyway to prevent Ligatures from happening in React Native applications?

We are using font "Roobert" which is combining letters "f" and "i" into a ligature.

```
      <Text
        style={{
          fontFamily: "roobert",
        }}
      >
        Profile
      </Text>
```

[image: React Native ligature]

It also seems to happen with increased letter spacing.

[image: Ligature with increased letter spacing]

I would just like to have normal "profile" text without ligatures.

Comment: The css declaration in the css @font-face rule `font-variant-ligatures: none;` might work?

Comment: This is React Native though, not css

Comment: Ah sorry. What about passing the property to the style object? `fontVariantLigatures: 'none'`?

Comment: That does nothing :/

Comment: There is this fontVariant https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#fontvariant , but none of the options seem to disable ligatures

Comment: There is a github issue, but [it's been closed](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20285)

Comment: Just curious: Why don't you want the ligatures? Are you really expanding letter spacing like that?

Comment: Hmm. Well maybe this question was just prompted by the initial shock upon realising that ligatures exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U+200B character can be used to remove this.

By adding U+200B character in between the characters that would from the ligature, you can prevent ligature from forming.

So: Prof​ile (has invisible char)

instead of: Profile

https://unicode-table.com/en/200B/